# How to find all possible matches in the given string for the given pattern without using regex in Java?

Tags: java

I have found out how to get substring for a given regex. I also have found how to use regex pattern matcher concept to find matches of given pattern with given string.
Example of Java Regular Expressions" is given here
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-regex

```
import java.util.regex.*;  
public class RegexExample1{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
//1st way  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".s");//. represents single character  
Matcher m = p.matcher("as");  
boolean b = m.matches();  

//2nd way  
boolean b2 = Pattern.matches(".s", "as");  

System.out.println(b+" "+b2);  
}}
```

But I am unable to find given string for given pattern not using regex.Is there any other way to find out.Please, Let me know..

Comment: Using the same pattern ? **With a Regex syntax ?** See what is the problem with your question ;)

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Build your own parser using lex and yacc.... oh wait those use regex too.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why is using regex not good enough for you? What kind of pattern matching do you want to do?

Comment: use JavaVerbalExpressions: https://github.com/VerbalExpressions/JavaVerbalExpressions

Comment: @jbiWeisendorf quote: _VerbalExpressions is a Java library that helps to construct difficult **regular expressions**_

Comment: You want to write your own regular expression matcher? Or do you use some other pattern syntax?

Comment: How can we write our own regular expression matcher to find all possible matches in the given string for given pattern?